# Me.Keyup does not work unless I make panel visible then click button to close it

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010, keydown, keyup

I set up a very simple app with a webbrowser control and an invisible panel with 2 buttons and a text box to use for entering a url.

When I start the app no amount of pressing keys will do anything even with ridiculously simple code like this.

```
  Private Sub Frm_Main_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    My.Settings.Reload()
    Dim URL As New Uri(Application.StartupPath & "\" & My.Settings.path)
    WebBrowser1.Url = URL
    TXT_URL.Text = My.Settings.path
    Me.KeyPreview = True
 End Sub



Private Sub Frm_Main_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    Beep()
End Sub
```

However if I click the menu option to show the panel then immediately click the button on the panel to set pnl_url.visible=false then I can press keys and get a response from the keyup routine.

Any ideas? I can't figure out what to do to get the app tostart accepting keystrokes without forcing the user to click something. me.focus or 'control'.focus isn't doing anything either.

written in Visual Studio 2010

********************************EDIT***************************************************
I had figured out it was the web browser control that was choking it but couldn't figure out how to get it to cooperate. a friend of mine fixed it for me.

```
        Private Sub WebBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.PreviewKeyDown
        Dim ee As New KeyEventArgs(e.KeyData)

        Me.Frm_Main_KeyUp(sender, ee)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This goes wrong because the web browser has the focus when your app starts up.  A browser implements its own runtime environment that's also interested in keystrokes.  Javascript for example has access to a key events.  By monkeying with your panel, you probably ended up giving another control the focus, now the KeyUp event works.

You'll need a bigger weapon than Form.KeyPreview.  You can also override the form's ProcessCmdKey() method.  It will run, even when the browser has the focus.  Beware however that this method was intended to allow you to implement shortcut keys.  Like pressing F1 to show help.  Command keys, thus the name.  It isn't suitable for normal keyboard processing.

And of course you'll still break whatever script runs in the browser.  Which might well want to see a shortcut key like that as well.

Do consider that the fundamental problem is that your approach is broken.